# component gets load before destroying another in angular 2 router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components, angular2-cli, angular2-modules

I am facing issue in Angular 2 router view rendering. any help would be appreciated.

**Current Scenario:**

While navigating from one view to another, Angular 2 router loads the new view on top of the previous one without destroying the previous view.

[Here is the Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScRbK.png)

(The red line representing different pages where you can see actually 3 views getting loaded on top of each other).]

**Expected Scenario:**

The router should first destroy the first view and then loads the next.

**Routes file**

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'child1',         
            component: ChildComponent1
        },
        {
            path: 'child2',
            component: ChildComponent2
        },
        {
            path: 'child3/:id',
            component: ChildComponent3
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'SiblingComponent',
        component: SiblingComponent
    }
]
```

then in my App Module I am importing these routes as followed.

**App.module**

```
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
  ]
 })
```

btw. I am using `"@angular/router": "^4.0.0"` and the application is built using `angular-cli`

Also, I am not actually sure if that's an Angular 2 router issue or some other thing is the root cause of it.
**EDIT**

Here is the HTML of the components

**App.component.html** `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

**Parent.component.html** `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

**Child1.component.html**  `<div>Child 1</div>`

**Child2.component.html**  `<div>Child 2</div>`

**Child3.component.html**  `<div>Child 3</div>`

**Sibling.component.html** `<div>Sibling Component</div>`

Comment: Post the HTML where your views are held (their parebt component if any) and routed please.

Comment: I have added the HTML now

Comment: Do you have any error in your console?

Comment: Nope. console is clean

Comment: With the html you posted I can't reproduce your bug. Please post your **complete and minimal HTML** so we can help. Also, you could try to update your angular-router dependency. If I'm not mistaking, there were some bugs with router in the first relzase of the angular-cli 4